# Populated timezones table for mysql (hosted)

Tags: mysql, timezone, hosting

I have a site hosted in php&mysql.

I'm looking for a table in Mysql with all timezones names and +/- minutes to add to UTC to get the user's local time.

So simple as 2 cols:

**TimeZoneName | AddMinutes**

Where I can download the script to get this table populated?

Thanks in advance.

---

Edit : Add information and maybe an answer

Looking for this table, I found this page that have few tables with:

zone_id , abbreviation , time_start , gmt_offset and dst.

I thing there is a good point to start, then fix the time if dst is set.

http://timezonedb.com/download

Really i was searching something like this for a couple of days.
Now i add some extra words and found that page.

Comment: How are you planning on dealing with daylight saving time? What sort of "name" do you expect? I think time zones are more complicated than you're expecting them to be.

Comment: My idea is that the user choose a time zone, then I add the difference in minutes.
Users always can change the timezone by a combobox in php.
I think that several sites do the same.

Comment: My time zone is "Europe/London" (well, that's the IANA/TZDB ID). In winter, that's UTC+0. In summer, that's UTC+1. What does it look like in your table? Note that the table in timezonedb has more than those two columns.

Comment: Maybe it just to reduce a 24 or 48 rows in ranges of 30 minutes, and DST on or off.

if you tell me that you are in +0 dst, I believe that i can  fix you time in the php code

Comment: No, I don't think you understand how complicated time zones are. Different zones may have the same *current* offset, but different rules about when they change DST, as well as different historical data.

Answer (score 1):

Both PHP and MySQL *already* have support for time zones.

Refer to:

- The PHP [Date and Time Related Extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/refs.calendar.php) documentation, which includes the `DateTimeZone` and `DateTime` classes
- The [MySQL Server Time Zone Support](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/time-zone-support.html) documentation.

You should also be familiar with the standard set of IANA time zones used by both, which are described in [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info), and [on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database).

You should not try to add your own tables, or copy them from somewhere else.  If you need time zone support in your database, use the tables generated by MySQL as described in that documentation.